# Get quotient and residue from a division executing just one operation

Tags: python, c++

I need to know how can i get quotient and residue from a division executing just one operation, using python or c++.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I suggest restricting your question to just one language, either Python or C++.  If you really need to know for both Python and C++, then probably posting two questions (one for each language) would be better.

Comment: For Python this function is listed in the documentation of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). You may have missed it when you looked there. Look again.

Comment: For C++, use `quotient = x/y;` and immediately follow with `remainder = x % y;`.  Set compiler optimizations to high.  Hopefully both compiler and processor will only do one division here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quotient, reminder = divmod(10, 3)
print(quotient, reminder)  # 3 1
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod

Answer (score 2):

For Python, the function you are looking for is called [divmod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
divmod(a, b)
```

Take two (non-complex) numbers as arguments and return a pair of numbers consisting of their quotient and remainder when using integer division. With mixed operand types, the rules for binary arithmetic operators apply. For integers, the result is the same as (a // b, a % b). For floating point numbers the result is (q, a % b), where q is usually math.floor(a / b) but may be 1 less than that. In any case q * b + a % b is very close to a, if a % b is non-zero it has the same sign as b, and 0 <= abs(a % b) < abs(b).